# Struggling with same issue. Any input on this?

Tags: java, mongodb, connection

```
MongoClientOptions.Builder options = MongoClientOptions.builder();
options.socketKeepAlive(true).maxWaitTime(100).connectTimeout(100);
MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient(host, options.build());
```

I get this because the pool has been closed, but I don't want the pool to be closed since my application is huge. I want the pool to continue till the end of the application or at-least one particular class. Any help will be appreciated.

```
Closed connection [connectionId{localValue:124, serverValue:8540}] to localhost:27017 because the pool has been closed.
```

Answer (score -1):

MongoDB provides multiple connection pool options check this [Mongo Connection Pool Options](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/)

**maxPoolSize**
The maximum number of connections in the connection pool. The default value is 100.

**minPoolSize**
The minimum number of connections in the connection pool. The default value is 0.

**maxIdleTimeMS**
The maximum number of milliseconds that a connection can remain idle in the pool before being removed and closed.

This option is not supported by all drivers.

**waitQueueMultiple**
A number that the driver multiples the maxPoolSize value to, to provide the maximum number of threads allowed to wait for a connection to become available from the pool. For default values, see the MongoDB Drivers and Client Libraries documentation.

**waitQueueTimeoutMS**
The maximum time in milliseconds that a thread can wait for a connection to become available. For default values, see the MongoDB Drivers and Client Libraries documentation.